Invoking Solana Programs
I was checking different ways to initialize a solana program. I am quiet new to field and expecting some support here.
I am running some VMs on a auto scaling group. I want to invoke a program when some events submitted from that VMs.
My current questions are,
When its auto scaling how can I invoke the program. I am using JS in my servers.
In my devnet setup I can generate a keypair and airdrop and send transaction to program to invoke it. How can I do it on main net?
and Are there any other ways to invoke the programs.
Thanks..

I'm going to assume that you are using the solana CLI to perform these operations since there isn't a lot of specific information to go on from your question.
To perform mainnet-beta operations, switch your local solana config to point to mainnet-beta
solana config set --url mainnet-beta 

confirm that everything is correct by running
solana config get

should output something like this
Config File: /home/jimii/.config/solana/cli/config.yml # solana cli config file path
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com # RPC URL, 
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed) # websocket URL
Keypair Path: /home/jimii/.config/solana/id.json # your local keypair 
Commitment: confirmed # commitment status. can be finalized, confirmed, processed

